# Total derivative only defined on open subset

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let's say that $f: M \to\mathbb{R}^n$, where $M \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, is totally differentiable at point $a$ so that we have an open subeset $U$ with $a \in U \subset M$.

Why does $U$ have to be an open set? What's wrong with it if you assume that $U$ is closed and $a$ lies on the edge of subset $U$?

**edit**

Why is it not sufficient to assume that $a$ is a limit point if you want to show the uniqueness of the total derivative?

Comment: There are notions though, where you can also consider a bounded set, but these rely on the definition for open sets. For another argument then below, see also here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/469735/699910).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Let's simplify the above example even further, take $M = \{ (x,y) \in \R^2 \mid x\in \R, y= 0\}$. And take $0 = F : M \to \R$ and investigate the differentiability from $F$ at $0$. Now, the point is, that you can not take any $h \in \R^2$ when looking at the difference quotient but only those for which $0+h = h \in M$ (see below), that is necessarily $h = (h_1,0)$. Hence take $A = (0,\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in \R$ then we get
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(0+h) - f(0) -(0,\lambda)^T \cdot(h_1,0)\|}{\|h\|} = 0.
$$

**Here some further thoughts and discussions:**

First let's observe, that the usual definition of when we call a linear map a differential is quite problematic for any closed set. Take for example a single point. Thats why in 1d one usually requires a non trivial (not just one point or empty) but otherwise arbitrary interval. So one has at least "enough" points.

With that one could agree that we should at least have a closed set $M$ in $\R^m$ (or even arbitrary set) but with the property that for any point $p$ in $M$, there is an open set $U$ in $\R^m$ with $p$ in it, such that $M\cap U$ has not an empty interior.

> The "usual" definition reads: Let $M \subset \R^m$ open, $p \in M$, then a function $f : M \to \R^n$ is called *differentiable* in $p$ if there is a linear map $A : \R^m \to \R^n$ such that for all $p+h$ that are contained in an (open) neighborhood $U \subset M$ of $p$ holds:
>   $$
> f(p+h) - f(p) = Ah + r(h) \qquad \text{where} \quad \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(h)}{\|h\|} = 0 ,\quad  r : 0\in dom(r)\subset \R^m \to \R^n.
> $$

Now, consider $K := \overline {M}$ (which is general enough, I guess), $f : K \to \R^n$ and take $p$ to be on the boundary (e.g. $p \in \partial M$), then the above definition does not make sense anymore, since there is no such neighborhood $U$. But lets try to fix it, by just requiring that the above is true for a neighborhood $U \subset \R^m$ of $p$ and for all $p+h$ that are contained in $U \cap K$. 
So far so good. Now what does $\lim_{h\to 0}$ mean now? It still means sending $h \in \R^m$ to $0 \in \R^m$ but now we only can take those sequences that are in the set $\{h \in \R^m : p+h \in U\cap K,\, h \neq 0\}$. I don't think that there is anything wrong with this approach and you can compare it with this [interesting discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1206144/699910). But as shown above you might loose uniqueness and (many) other properties.

**Extension**

Let me also mention a different approach, that actually is in use (in contrast to the above?!):

> Let $K \subset \R^m$ be an arbitrary (!) set, then $f : K \to R^n$ is called differentiable at $p \in K$, if there exists an open set $U \in \R^m$ that contains $p$ and a in $p$ differentiable function $\tilde F : U \to \R^n$ such that $\tilde F\big|_{U \cap K} = F$.

You can find it in Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds on page 645.

Thank you for this question. I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The issue if you do so is that you may lose the unicity of the (Fréchet) derivative.

To see it consider a map $f$ defined on a line $M \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ onto $\mathbb R$. You won’t be able to find a unique linear map of two variables that represents the derivative.

To figure it, just look at a constant map.

Comment: Ok, let be $M:=\{ {x \choose y} \vert x=y\}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f{x \choose y}=0$. If I consider the differential quotient the linear mapping $L=(0, 0)$ would be a derivative. But I don't understand how, in that case, it would be possible that there are any other derivatives than $L=(0, 0)$?

Comment: No. The $L$ you mention would not be the only derivative. Any $H=(\lambda, -\lambda)$ would work as for $(x,y)\in M$ you have $H(x,y)=H(x,x)=0$.

Comment: Do I always lose the uniqueness property if I don't assume *open sets*? Or inother words, is the *open set* property sufficient but not necessary to conclude uniqueness?

Comment: No. You may have unicity in that case.